# Implicit geometry typecast via trigger

Tags: qgis, postgis, ogc, geometry-conversion

Because OGC SFS is relatively strict when it comes to mixing Geometries with their MULTI- Counterparts, we came up with a solution to store everything as MULTI... and convert incoming geometries via BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE Triggers using `ST_Multi(NEW.geom)`.

So our tables are defined as

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS basins (
 id serial primary key,
 geom geometry(MULTIPOLYGON,31287)
 ...

);
```

And a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE Trigger ensures that POLYGON Features are also ST_MUlti´d

Now I recognized, that this won't work, because PostGIS won't accept any INSERTs with the wrong typmod, i.e. `geometry(POLYGON,31287)` altough these would be implicitely convertible to each other.

When I cannot solve this on the database side, I have to solve it on the application side. So the only way to solve it would be defining Views which accept all geometries and convert the geometry in the INSTEAD OF Trigger. Because QGIS for example relies heavily on the correct specific typmods to work in a performant manner, I end up using the Table (with correct metadata) for viewing and the views for writing, which I think is very awkward to use.

Are there any better patterns to streamline this a bit?

Comment: Since other options are rare, I'd suggest to stick to generic typed *Views*; QGIS does handle them more elegantly these days, and if you are concerned about performance, you could `CREATE INDEX ON <table> ((ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_MultiPolygon'));` (I am not sure right now if QGIS calls `ST_GeometryType` or `GeometryType`; you need to find out and change the above string accordingly)

Comment: By "performance" I meant the fact, that QGIS tends to table scan geometry types, if they aren't defined specificlly in the geometry_columns.... so you CAN define the table with typemod `geometry(GEOMETRY,31287)` and you would be able to store any geometrytype then, BUT QGIS get ridicolously slow then when you load or save the project file, because it is doing table scans on these tables then to guarantee the geometrytypes. So you definitely SHOULD NOT use a generic typemod.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why QGIS wouldn't be affected by an index on the geometry type for its 'table scans' (I can't check the actual SQL, but someone must have made sure it *ignores* that index), but why not simply wrap your `INSERT` geometry in `ST_Multi`?

Comment: Because a Table Scan (to find all distinct geometrytypes used in the table) don't use an index per definition.

Yes, thats the point, we have to wrap our INSERTs in ST_Multi on the Application side instead of using a database side trigger doing that so that any application using this database don't have to worry about sending the correct geometrytype (as a lot of clients actually really don't worry at all)

Comment: A *Seq Scan* is opposing the *Index Scan* indeed, but `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` ('*to find all distinct geometrytypes*') are happily reading any index in place; correct me if QGIS is doing sth. else entirely. There is no way to bypass PostgreSQL column type constraints directly; you could try and modify the PostGIS `GEOMETRY` type definition to include a specific cast between the typemods. That'd be a C function implementation and needs a rebuild of PostGIS.

Comment: I was afraid that this might be the case...still hoping that some core PostGIS guys (like p. ramsey himself) might mention their opinion on this topic ;)